# need to draw an Google marker image via C# Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, graphicspath

I need to draw an Google marker image via C# Graphics 
for that i;ll need the exact coordinates of Google marker 
how can i do that Please help .
My Current Code is .

```
private void Shape8(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            int startMarker = 0;
            int MarkerDiameter = 30;
            int EllipseDiameter = 15;

            const int StartX = 150;
            const int StartY = 350;

            int X = StartX;
            int Y = StartY;

            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            Rectangle ellipse = new Rectangle(X, Y, EllipseDiameter, EllipseDiameter);
            path.AddEllipse(ellipse);
            path.CloseFigure();

            X = X + (EllipseDiameter / 2) - (MarkerDiameter / 2);
            Y = Y - (EllipseDiameter * 2) - (MarkerDiameter / 2);

            startMarker = StartY - 10 - (Convert.ToInt32(MarkerDiameter * 1.5));//Space Between marker and circle.
            AddMarker8(ref path, X, startMarker, StartX, StartY, EllipseDiameter, MarkerDiameter, "Concept1");

            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Pink, path);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, ellipse);

            path.CloseAllFigures();

        }

 private void AddMarker8(ref GraphicsPath path, int X, int Y, int StartX, int StartY, int EllipseDiameter, int MarkerDiameter, string conceptName)
        {
            float startAngle = 180.0F;
            float sweepAngle = 180.0F;
            int fontStyle = (int)FontStyle.Regular;

            path.AddString(conceptName, new FontFamily("Arial"), fontStyle, 15, new Point(X + (MarkerDiameter / 2), Y - 15), lblFormat);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(X, Y, MarkerDiameter, MarkerDiameter);
            path.AddArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);

            Point lastpoint = new Point(X + (MarkerDiameter / 2), (Y + (MarkerDiameter * 2)) - (MarkerDiameter / 2));
            path.AddCurve(new Point[] {
                new Point(X+(MarkerDiameter), Y + (MarkerDiameter / 2)), //a
                new Point((X +MarkerDiameter)-(MarkerDiameter/4) ,(Y +(MarkerDiameter ))) ,//A.5
                lastpoint ,//c
                new Point(X +(MarkerDiameter / 4) ,(Y +(MarkerDiameter ))) ,//B.5
                new Point(X, Y + (MarkerDiameter / 2))//b
                    }, 0.5f);

            path.CloseFigure();
        }
```

Comment: When you say "exact coordinates of Google marker", do you mean the exact shape?

Comment: Yes and i also need to re-size it .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
    private void DrawMarker(int X, int Y, double Scale, Color BorderColor, Color FillColor, PaintEventArgs e, char Letter = '\0')
    {
        Graphics G1 = e.Graphics;
        Pen Pen1 = new Pen(BorderColor, 8);
        SolidBrush Brush1 = new SolidBrush(BorderColor);
        SolidBrush Brush2 = new SolidBrush(FillColor);

        G1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        G1.ResetTransform();
        G1.ScaleTransform(Convert.ToSingle(0.4 * Scale), Convert.ToSingle(0.4 * Scale));

        GraphicsPath GraphicsPath1 = new GraphicsPath();
        GraphicsPath1.AddBeziers(new Point(X + 51, Y + 169), new Point(X + 47, Y + 137), new Point(X + 42, Y + 107), new Point(X + 14, Y + 77));
        GraphicsPath1.AddBeziers(new Point(X + 87, Y + 77), new Point(X + 62, Y + 107), new Point(X + 55, Y + 137), new Point(X + 51, Y + 169));

        GraphicsPath GraphicsPath2 = new GraphicsPath();
        GraphicsPath2.AddEllipse(X + 5, Y + 5, 92, 92);
        G1.FillPath(Brush2, GraphicsPath2);
        G1.DrawPath(Pen1, GraphicsPath2);
        G1.SetClip(new Rectangle(X, Y + 85, 103, 84));
        G1.FillPath(Brush2, GraphicsPath1);
        G1.DrawPath(Pen1, GraphicsPath1);
        G1.ResetClip();

        if (Letter != '\0')
        {
            Font Font1 = new Font("Arial", 52, FontStyle.Bold);
            StringFormat StringFormat1 = new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            G1.DrawString(Convert.ToString(Letter), Font1, Brush1, new Rectangle(X, Y, 103, 103), StringFormat1);

            Font1.Dispose();
            StringFormat1.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            G1.FillEllipse(Brush1, new Rectangle(X + 32, Y + 32, 37, 37));
        }

        Pen1.Dispose();
        Brush1.Dispose();
        Brush2.Dispose();
        GraphicsPath1.Dispose();
        GraphicsPath2.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawMarker(0, 0, 0.5, Color.Black, Color.Tomato, e, Convert.ToChar("A"));
        DrawMarker(80, 0, 0.8, Color.Black, Color.Red, e, Convert.ToChar("B"));
        DrawMarker(160, 0, 1, Color.Black, Color.Linen, e, Convert.ToChar("C"));
        DrawMarker(210, 0, 1.3, Color.Black, Color.Orange, e, Convert.ToChar("D"));
        DrawMarker(260, 0, 1.6, Color.Black, Color.Green, e);
    }
```

after running it, the result should be like this

[image]